# Is it possible to to get an empty string in a list when there is no element, using CSS selector?

Tags: css, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape some items, which are on the same page, using Scrapy.
HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container" id="1">
    <span class="title">
        product-title1
    </span>
    <div class="description">
        product-desc
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        1.0
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract name, description and price.

Unfortunately, sometimes product doesn't have the description and HTML look like this:

```
<div class="container" id="2">
    <span class="title">
        product-title2
    </span>
    <div class="price">
        2.0
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am using CSS selectors which returns list of all elements existing on the website:

`title = response.css('span[class="title"]').extract()`

> ['product-title1', 'product-title2', 'product-title3']

`description = response.css('div[class="description"]').extract()`

> ['desc1','desc3']

`price = response.css('div[class="price"]').extract()`

> ['1.0','2.0','3.0']

Is it possible to get for example an empty string in place of missing 'desc2' when description object isn't there, using CSS selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to rewrite you code:

```
for section in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
    title = section.xpath('./span[@class="title"]/text()').get(default='not-found') # you can use any default value here or just empty string
    desctiption = section.xpath('./div[@class="description"]').get()
    price = section.xpath('./div[@class="price"]/text()').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..

```
for section in response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]'):
    title = section.xpath('./span[@class="title"]/text()').get()
    desctiption_tag = section.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'description')]")
    if desctiption_tag:
        desctiption = section.xpath('./div[@class="description"]').get()
    else:
        desctiption = "String"
    price = section.xpath('./div[@class="price"]/text()').get()
```